# PhantomJS not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, phantomjs, capybara

Hello i am trying to update phantomJS, for my Capybara testing. This is on my vagrant env.
my current version is

1.9.2

tried to update with

```
sudo npm -g install phantomjs-prebuilt
```

but when i type

```
phantomjs -v
got same 1.9.2
```

then i tried to install gem for ruby

```
gem install phantomjs
```

and and into env.rb file

```
require 'phantomjs'
```

but when i start tests got error

```
cannot load such file -- phantomjs (LoadError)
```

Can anyone explain to me how this works, i am totally new to this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you using bundler? did you add it to your Gemfile?

Comment: tried bundle update phantomjs but Could not find gem 'phantomjs'

Answer (score 0):

Solution was in adding phantom js in gem file

```
group(:test) do
  gem 'phantomjs'
  gem 'test-unit'
  gem 'cucumber'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'rest-client'
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem "nokogiri", "~> 1.6.1"
  gem "json", "~> 1.8.1"
  gem "capybara-angular"
end
```